# Joining two ethernet cables: strip and solder or buy an adapter?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cat5, cat5e

I need to connect two Ethernet cables together. Right now, neither end is terminated. I think my two options are to either terminate both ends and then use something like this RJ45 Coupler F/F Straight Connector, or to just strip each wire and join them, either by twisting or soldering them together. Is either way clearly better than the other?

[image: RJ45 Coupler F/F Straight Connector]

Comment: If you've got the connectors on the ends already it's best to use a gazinta/gazouta (coupler). If you need to join cables which don't already have connectors you should probably use a purpose made splice block.  Simply twisting the wires together would not be reliable, since corrosion would soon compromise the connections.  Soldering is more reliable but tedious and inconvenient.  Wire nuts could be used but they're bulky and fairly easily knocked loose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CAT5e/6 junction boxes are available for splicing cables without needing to terminate, twist, or soldier.

Junction boxes are better for permanent cabling, as they're more secure than terminated ends paired with a coupler, or twisted/soldiered. Cables with these junction boxes won't be pulled apart at the splice point, unlike with other splice methods.

Examples:

- [Punch-down junction box](http://www.electriduct.com/Junction-Box-Punch-Down-Type.html)
- [Punch-down 110 block](http://deepsurplus.com/Network-Structured-Wiring/Ethernet-CAT5e-Junction-Box/Ethernet-CAT-5E-Junction-Box-110-Punch-down-Style-White)
- [Punch-down shielded 110 block](http://www.computercableinc.com/ccinc/products.jsp?sub=CAT5E+Keystone+Jacks+%26Couplers&id=3878)

Note: I've never actually purchased from any of these particular storefronts. I'm simply linking to them to show examples of junction boxes.

Answer (score 0):

In a pinch I've been known to strip it, twist the inner wires together together, and wrap with electrical tape. Its a ghetto soluton, but effective if you do not move the cable around to much. That being said that coupler is like $2 so it seems like you have several good options.

Comment: One needs to be aware that twisted wires will eventually fail, due to corrosion.

Comment: Yup... definitely ghetto. Still useful in a pinch.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't hesitate to do it for a short-term fix (and I know a few fone company tricks that would make it more permanent, but they're a bit to involved to describe easily).